# Whatsapp Issue in Notification

Tags: whatsapp

Suddenly the Whatsapp notifications stopped on Lumia 535 in the Banner area and on the main screen. Also no sound is coming when the Whatsapp message came. Please let me know if any solution for the same.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest whatsapp update version 2.11.690.0. ?? This version comes with few big fixes and improvements ..